# How to retrieve a list of updated messages via IMAP

Tags: email, imap, polling

*This seems like a straightforward question, but I haven't had any good answers from the IMAP RFC or anything I've been able to Google*

I'm writing an IMAP client which periodically polls large mailboxes every few minutes.

While being able to figure out which messages are new is easy enough by using UIDNEXT, what I would also like to do is track other events such as if a message has been read or unread, or if it has been deleted.

Since the polling I am doing is frequent, and the mailboxes are large, I would ideally like to simply retrieve a list of deltas since the last update, rather than download an entire mailbox and then compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of reconnecting and polling everytime you could keep the connection open and tell the imap server to push the mailbox changes using the [IDLE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2177) or [NOTIFY](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5465) IMAP Extension